# Creating a column by matching values with another table?

Tags: clickhouse

I'm new to clickhouse and I'm having trouble creating a column by referencing values of another table.

The database I'm working with has a table data_geo which has a column "numa" that contains a certain identifier string. There is another table users_oldid_2_newid that has two columns:

- old_id: the different values that appear in the "numa" table.
- id: an integer

It is basically a mapping from a string identifier to an integer identifier.

I would like to add a column to data_geo called "new_numa" that has the integer identifier corresponding to the "numa" string of that given row.

I tried this query

```
ALTER TABLE data_geo
ADD COLUMN new_numa INT
AFTER numa;

UPDATE data_geo
new_numa = users_oldid_2_newid.id
FROM users_oldid_2_newid
WHERE data_geo.numa = users_oldid_2_newid.old_id;
```

But got

QL Error [62] [07000]: Code: 62. DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 1 ('UPDATE') (line 1, col 1): UPDATE data_geo
new_numa = COALESCE(users_oldid_2_newid.id, NULL)
FROM users_oldid_2_newid
WHERE data_geo.numa = users_oldid_2_newid.old_id. Expected one of: Query, Query with output, EXPLAIN, SELECT query, possibly with UNION, list of union elements, SELECT query, subquery, possibly with UNION, SELECT subquery, SELECT query, WITH, FROM, SELECT, SHOW CREATE QUOTA query, SHOW CREATE, SHOW [FULL] [TEMPORARY] TABLES|DATABASES|CL (...)

I also tried creating a dictionary but didn't manage to make it work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to understand how wokrs `ALTER TABLE .. UPDATE`
look official documentation
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter#mutations
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/update

Second, read about dictionaries and dictGet
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/dictionary
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/dictionaries#cache

And last, look to update via dictGet
https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-queries-and-syntax/update-via-dictionary/